# Set typeface to alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, typeface

I have an alertdialog and i use typeface for title and message and button of alertdialog.
The problem is that the title and message view with the typeface but the buttons not?
Why
This is my code

```
public boolean functionInQuestion(MissingParameters ... parameters) {
    Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/hhh.ttf");
    TextView mysite = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView fbpage = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView content5 = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView Mytitle5 = new TextView(mainn.this);

    mysite.setText("google");
    fbpage.setText("fb");
    Mytitle5.setText("google and facebook");
    content5.setText("linka to google and facebook");

    mysite.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    fbpage.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    content5.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    Mytitle5.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainn.this);
    builder.setView(content5);
    builder.setCustomTitle(Mytitle5);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.about);

    builder.setPositiveButton(fbpage.getText(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // When LeftButton click, source implementing is put here.  
            String url = "http://www.facebook.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton(mysite.getText(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            // When CenterButton click, source implementing is put here.
            String url = "http://www.google.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    builder.show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it Must work :)

```
public boolean functionInQuestion(MissingParameters ... parameters) {
    Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/hhh.ttf");
    TextView mysite = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView fbpage = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView content5 = new TextView(mainn.this);
    TextView Mytitle5 = new TextView(mainn.this);

    mysite.setText("google");
    fbpage.setText("fb");
    Mytitle5.setText("google and facebook");
    content5.setText("linka to google and facebook");

    mysite.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    fbpage.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    content5.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    Mytitle5.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainn.this);
    builder.setView(content5);
    builder.setCustomTitle(Mytitle5);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.about);

    builder.setPositiveButton(fbpage.getText(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // When LeftButton click, source implementing is put here.  
            String url = "http://www.facebook.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton(mysite.getText(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            // When CenterButton click, source implementing is put here.
            String url = "http://www.google.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Dialog dialog =builder.show();
                Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
                button.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
                Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button3);
                button2.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i said not working... but it was write mistake.... it's not working Kam Wave

Comment: if you are using negative button use `Button button_negative = (Button) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button2);`